# I'm trying to repeat a part of code in a text adventure type game when the player tries to go back on an area, is there a way to do this?

Tags: c#, adventure

I'm a beginner and I am creating a text adventure game. I am trying to make an option where you can go back (eg. you enter a room and can type go back to go to the previous room and repeat the code on the last room).

Here is my code:

```
// Decision 2
Console.WriteLine("in front of you there are three paths, which path do you take? \n 1 \n 2 \n 3 ");
      
string decision2 = Console.ReadLine();

if (decision2 == "1")
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the first path.");
}
else if (decision2 == "2")
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the second path ");  
}

{
    Console.WriteLine("you have chosen the third  path ");
}
     
// Decision 3
if (decision2 == "1")
{
    Console.WriteLine("At the end of the first path there is a chest, do you want to open it? \n yes\n no");
    string decision3 = Console.ReadLine();

    if (decision3 == "yes")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You open the chest and see a bomb, you take the bomb and put it in your inventory, what do you do next? \n check the room \n check inventory \n or go back ");
        string decision4 = Console.ReadLine();
```

I want to repeat the part in which you decide which path to take if the player types 'go back' in the last part.

Comment: Back tracking as you describe is one thing, another is, you will need some “mechanism” for the user to “signal” that they wanted to go back one step. In other words, how would the user tell the code that they wanted to go back one step?

Comment: To simplify things, have you considered making something like a “Decision” METHOD. This method would take a `string` question and possibly a `string` array of choices. Then have it return the users selected choice. In addition you could incorporate your “go-back-one” as a choice. This should reduce the code you have to write and also makes it easier to make changes for any “Decision” you present to the user. Or possibly a “Decision” class that has a question property and a choices collection property. Then you could wrap everything pertaining to a “Decision” into this class. Just a thought.